# MinGW won't copy libstdc++-6.dll to the output folder even though the address is correct

Tags: qt, dll, makefile, mingw

I want to deploy my Qt program. I use qmake to generate the Makefile from my .pro file. And then I run mingw32-make, and finally mingw32-make install to copy necessary dlls to the output folder. I am copying 9 dlls, all in the same folder (Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/bin). All of them get copied without an issue, except for libstdc++-6.dll.

I have checked the generated Makefile to see if there was anything spelled incorrectly. I have also checked the paths and everything. I am doing the same thing for all 9 files, but only libstdc++-6.dll has an issue with being copied.

Below lines are from my Makefile install target. I covered the copy target location.

```
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\Qt5Core.dll <COPY_TARGET>
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\Qt5Gui.dll <COPY_TARGET>
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\Qt5OpenGL.dll <COPY_TARGET>
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\Qt5PrintSupport.dll <COPY_TARGET>
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\Qt5Svg.dll <COPY_TARGET>
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\Qt5Widgets.dll <COPY_TARGET>
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll <COPY_TARGET>
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll <COPY_TARGET>
-$(INSTALL_FILE) C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\libstdc++-6.dll <COPY_TARGET>
```

I want to say again that, `C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\libstdc++-6.dll` does exist.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Off-topic: Note that you can use windeployqt.exe to copy the Qt DLLs and needed plugins.

Comment: Thank you Nikos. When I deploy for myself, I use windeployqt. But I am preparing a project for people to use so I once I know all the necessary dlls, I try to copy them to the output folder using qmake's INSTALLS tag in my .pro file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters "+" are sometimes problematic in Windows filenames, so enclose a path to the file in quotes:

```
-$(INSTALL_FILE) "C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\libstdc++-6.dll" <COPY_TARGET>
```

Comment: thank you very much, that solved it. I would need a way to force qmake to put those quotes itself though, because I don't wanna go into the Makefile every time and scroll all the way down to make this change. Do you know a way I can get qmake to do it automatically? I've tried putting the quotes in the .pro file but it does not add them to the Makefile

Comment: @Deniz Try writing it as `$$shell_quote("libstdc++-6.dll")` in the qmake project file.

Comment: @NikosC. No luck. I've tried all possible combinations with that but it did not work.